# How to play youtube vidoe using SWFLoader?

Tags: apache-flex, youtube

How can i play youtube video using SWFLoader?

Currently, i can play only 1 video at a time (suppose its name is A), if i try to play video B it doesnt play it. but if again i play vidoe A, it works.

Any guidance?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you download "Adobe Tour de Flex" you have a lot of tutorials and working examples also about YOUTUBE API for Flash, this is a working example:

http://tourdeflex.adobe.com/holly/YouTubeSample/YouTubeEmbedPlayer.html

Having Tuor de Flex in your Pc you can also see the code (MXML or AS3)